Let web service response fail on io.ReadAll in unit test
I have a program that calls a web service and I want to write a unit test that checks the correct failure handling (nothing fancy). I use net/http/httptest to simulate the web service (backend). But I haven't figured out so far, how to return a response that fails on the io.ReadAll(res.Body).
The simplified code to call the web service is this:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func apiCall(url string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(context.Background(), http.MethodGet, url, nil)

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    // This is the part I want to check by letting the io.ReadAll fail
    resBody, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return resBody, err
}

The unit test looks like this:
package main

import (
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/require"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"
)

func TestIt(t *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(_ http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        // How can I make the io.ReadAll(res.Body) return an error?
    }))

    defer server.Close()

    _, err := apiCall(server.URL)
    require.Error(t, err)
}

Maybe I am on the wrong track with the httptest. If there is another or better way to test it, just let me know.
Here is also an link to the playground

I doubt you can trigger a failure of io.ReadAll from the server side. Use a slow sending server and a timeout on the client side thats shorter than the server needs to send. API calls should have sensible timeouts anyway.

But as I am using httptest to simulate the server, is this possible?

Let me repeat "I doubt you can trigger a failure of io.ReadAll from the server side." It doesn't matter what you use on the server side, be it net/http/httptest, MSI, Apache or whatnot. Okay, you can do a real slow send triggering the (30s?) default timeout of the DefaultClient. Just implement proper timeout in the client.

Does this answer your question? How to mock http.Client Do method

I'm not sure it is practical enough, because the error situation I made below doesn't occur normally.
But if we focus on only the coverage of the code at the test, we can do it like this.
Code
func TestIt(t *testing.T) {
    server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Length", "50")
        _, _ = w.Write([]byte("a"))
    }))

    defer server.Close()

    _, err := apiCall(server.URL)
    require.Error(t, err)
}

Then you get an error at io.ReadAll(res.Body) at the apiCall code, saying unexpected EOF
Go playground. https://go.dev/play/p/GLFiozJb_nO
Reference. https://github.com/h2non/gock/issues/75
Why does it happen?
    // ContentLength records the length of the associated content. The
    // value -1 indicates that the length is unknown. Unless Request.Method
    // is "HEAD", values >= 0 indicate that the given number of bytes may
    // be read from Body.
    ContentLength int64

The comment says the above. ContentLength is from the response Content-Length header. Client expects the 50 bytes of data by ContentLength but it encounters EOF right after only a byte. So it returns an error.
If you want to see the deep-side, you can find it sets the Reader's N (bytes to read) here. You can follow how it is used by using the debug tool at your IDE.

First, you define the error you want to return
var errTest = errors.New("test")

Then a mock body that returns this error when read:
type MockBody struct{}

func (m MockBody) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return 0, errTest
}

func (m MockBody) Close() error {
    return nil
}

It has to be a io.ReadCloser.
Now, define a mock client returning this body:
type httpClient interface {
    Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
}

type MockClient struct{}

func (MockClient) Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    return &http.Response{
        Body: MockBody{},
    }, nil
}

The mock client (and http.DefaultClient) fulfill your httpClient interface, so let's use that in apiCall:
func apiCall(ctx context.Context, client httpClient, url string) ([]byte, error) {
    req, _ := http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, http.MethodGet, url, nil)

    res, _ := client.Do(req)

    resBody, err := io.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return resBody, err
}

Now, test your function with a mock client (use http.DefaultClient in production):
func TestIt(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    _, err := apiCall(ctx, MockClient{}, "")

    if !errors.Is(err, errTest) {
        t.Errorf("Expected test error, got %v.", err)
    }
}

Try it on the Go Playground.
